# javascript function fails with error a ReferenceError about a variable not being defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    //select all siblings with same value in third column
     thisTR.siblings().filter(function() {
          if ($('td',this).eq(2).text() == $('td', thisTR).eq(2).text() ) {

               var tds = $(this).find('td');
                console.log($(this));
                var tr =$("<tr/>");
                tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(0).text() + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(2).text() + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
                tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));
                $('#selected_users').append(tr);                                
                };
    });
```

I am trying to create a function out of the logic that creates and appends a new  to the selected_users table, because I do this more than once in my code.

Here's the function I've made:

```
var add_to_selected_users = function(row){
        var tds = row.find('td');
        var tr =$("<tr/>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(0).text() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(2).text() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
        tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));
        $('#selected_users').append(tr);
}
```

So I've modified the main code to try to call this function like so:

```
    thisTR.siblings().filter(function() {
           if ($('td',this).eq(2).text() == $('td', thisTR).eq(2).text() ) {
               add_to_selected_users($(this));
           };
    });
```

**Problem**

When I call the function, I'm getting an error message that says:

> ReferenceError: id is not defined

and it's failing on the line of code in the function where I do this:

```
tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));
```

This code doesn't fail when i just have it embedded in the if statement, and not a part of the function.

**what I've Tried So Far**

I've tried to change the way I call the method from this:

```
add_to_selected_users($(this));
```

to this:

```
add_to_selected_users(this);
```

But that didn't make a difference.  Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: `tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));`  <<<where does id come from there?  looks pretty undefined to me

Comment: yup, you're all right.  my copy / paste skills are lacking.  i missed one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no id variable defined.

```
tr.attr('id', id.substring(4));
```

This line is using a variable called id and trying to call a function on it called substring.

```
id.substring(4)
```

Nowhere in your code have you defined the "id" variable.

Comment: my bad.  I forgot to copy "var id = this.id;"  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the ID of the row:

```
tr.attr('id', row.attr('id').substring(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the `id` as the error says. That means, in the parent scope the id is missing. You can prevent the error in saying

```
if(typeof id == 'undefined' || id == null) id = ...
```

This will prevent the error and you will define the `id` again, because that's what needs to be done.